# How do I create a partial overlay on a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecylerView` with a list of items, let's say **30** items. If any part of the top **20** items is visible, I want it to be covered with a "curtain" or scrim which is partially transparent, and says *Locked* in the middle of the visible scrim.

[image: An example of the scrim covering a certain set of items when they're visible]

I can't just add an overlay to the `ViewHolder` which I make visible for the first 20 items, because the *Locked* text needs to be centred on the entire overlay, and move as the user scrolls and less of the overlay is visible. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: I think you should tag the programming language that you are using

Comment: I've rewritten your question if that's ok, I hope I've got the details right! It's an interesting problem, and I think it's been downvoted because you didn't go into much detail. I'm not sure how to do it off-hand (it's the text in the middle that makes it tricky) but hopefully someone can help! Also, you might want to say what you want to happen if the visible area is too small (just don't show the text? Fade it out as it gets close to some minimum value?)

Comment: @cactustictacs oh Im sorry, the text doesn't get centered in the curtain. Let's say the text should maintain a 100px margin bottom spacing

Comment: Feel free to edit it - it's your question! But whether it's centred or relative to the bottom, it's still an overlay that needs to calculate the visible region. But if you *are* positioning it relative to the bottom, and you're not too fussed about exactly where it is, Andrei's answer could work for you - add an overlay view and *Locked* `TextView` to the item layout, make the overlay visible for the first 20 items, and make the text visible for item 18 or whatever. Kinda janky but it could work out ok!

Comment: @cactustictacs im sorry, I made a video where you can see the result more clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927918/how-to-show-a-overlay-at-a-recyclerview-in-android-see-video

Comment: @Nahro don't post a new question, just update this one

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what you want. But it looks like you want to hide your card. So when your card is bloked *curtain is visable* otherwise *curtain is gone*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        tools:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                tools:text="Some text"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/curtain"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#40000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcUQw.png)

Comment: Thats not quite what I want. I have recylerview list of items. Let's say, a list  of 30 items. Now the top 20 of this list needs to be overlayed with a black "curtain" and a text, saying locked.

Comment: I think the problem is the OP needs that text centred on the overlay, so at some point you're going to need to calculate where the bottom of the visible overlay is (bottom of the last overlaid `ViewHolder`) and decide where to place the `TextView` (or whether to show it at all, if the visible area is too small)

Comment: Here is a better explanation of what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927918/how-to-show-a-overlay-at-a-recyclerview-in-android-see-video